# inherit one table from another

Tags: python, odoo

I want to inherit an entire table to a new table, I have tried as follows but it doesn't work for me.

the table to inherit is as follows:

```
class Detalle_libro(models.Model):
    _name='proyecto_rc.detalle_libro'

    date=fields.Datetime(string="Fecha", related='tipo_movimiento_id.fecha', store=True)
    account_credit= fields.Char(string="Cuenta haber", related='cuenta_id.cuenta_haber1', store=True)
    total_debit=fields.Float(string="Debe", compute="_total_a_debe", inverse="_inverse_debe" , store=True)
    total_credit=fields.Float(string="Haber", compute="_total_a_haber", inverse="_inverse_haber" , store=True)
    account_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='proyecto_rc.account', string='Cuenta')
```

new table:

```
class Libro_diario(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'proyecto_rc.detail_book'

    date = fields.Datetime(string="Fecha")
    account_debit = (res.cuenta_id)
    account_credit = fields.Char(string="cuenta haber")
    total_debit=fields.Float(string="Debe")
    total_credit=fields.Float(string="Haber")
```

in the view:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="proyecto_rc.libro_inherit">  
    <field name="name">list of book</field>
    <field name="model">proyecto_rc.datail_book/field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="proyecto_rc.detail_book_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="date"/>
        <field name="cuenta_debit"/>
        <field name="cuenta_credit"/>
        <field name="total_debit"/>
        <field name="total_credit"/>
    </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="proyecto_rc.tree_detail_book_list">  
    <field name="name">list of book</field>
    <field name="model">proyecto_rc.detail_book</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="proyecto_rc.detail_book_action_window">
    <field name="name">add book</field>   
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">proyecto_rc.detail_book</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="proyecto_rc.tree_detail_book_list"/>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="Libro"
    id="proyecto_rc_libro_diario" 
    parent="menu_proyecto_rc" 
    action="proyecto_rc.detail_book_action_window"
    groups="proyecto_rc.grupo_administrador,proyecto_rc.grupo_cajera"/>

This is ODOO 12
```

Comment: The table to inherit is different and table which is inherited is different if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if you want to inherit a table and copy as new one.
copying existing model features and store in new table.

```
class Newmodel(models.Model):
_name = 'new.model'
_inherit = 'existing.model'
```

Comment: After doing what you do, because I always get to the baseline but then I don't know what steps to take, could you tell me?

Comment: The new model will inherit fields and functionalities of inherited model. you can directly call 'existing.model' fields in your new view of new.model.